# How can I upload a specific file (with whole filepath) to a PHP server?

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to upload a specific file (with a specific filepath) to a PHP server.
What javascript or HTML code should I use?
P.S. I'm a bit new to all this, so please help. :)

Comment: Google will turn up a lot here. Try a [tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php/)

Comment: @Trevor I have tried creating a form as explained here:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
But in that we can't specify a particular filename, so...

Comment: Use ftp client software like filezilla, cuteftp...etc

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can send the file and the desired path.  Then you can use *cp* or *mkdir* with the *--parents* option to create all the parent directories at once.

Comment: Is this the direction you want to take?  The tutorial in the comments of your question has more formal methods.  Basically, what do yo mean by you need to copy the entire directory structure?  Do you mean PHP will not know where it needs to place the file?  Only that it needs to upload and save some file?  Or can the logic for placing the file be part of the PHP?  The answer changes what needs to be done and how you'd go about doing it.